# Memory leak, using HttpClient and limited tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to run 10 concurrent web requests at a time, maximum. I'm controlling the number of web requests by a semaphore (see code below). However, when running, the memory grows - and eventually it has grown so much, that the application becomes real slow.

Firing up  `.NET Memory Profiler` shows the following 5 entries, which seems to be the cause (and also grows through out the applications lifetime):

[image]

At first glance, I just thought that the GC wasn't kicking in. But adding the following code and still see no effect worried me a little:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadKey();

    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
}
```

(taken from @Jon Skeets answer in [GC.Collect in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653730/gc-collect-in-a-loop))

---

The full code:

```
static async Task<Page> GetPageAsync(this HttpClient client, long maxContentLength, Uri requestUri)
{
    var loadTimeMeasure = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (response.Content)
        {
            var location = response.Headers.Location;

            var responseUri =
                location == null ? requestUri :
                location.IsAbsoluteUri ? location :
                new Uri(requestUri, location);

            var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

            var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.HasValue
                ? response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value : 0;

            Func<HtmlNode, long, Page> BuildPage = (htmlNode, loadTime) => new Page
            {
                RequestUri = requestUri,
                ResponseUri = responseUri,
                HTML = htmlNode,
                LoadTime = loadTime,
                StatusCode = response.StatusCode,
                Headers = ExtractHeaders(response),
                ContentLength = contentLength,
                ContentType = contentType.ToString()
            };

            if (contentLength > maxContentLength || !contentType.Contains("text/html"))
            {
                var page = BuildPage(null, loadTimeMeasure.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                response.Content.Dispose();
                return page;
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var page2 = BuildPage(TryMapToHtmlNode(content), loadTimeMeasure.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return page2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (response.Content != null)
            response.Content.Dispose();
        return null;
    }
}

static HtmlNode TryMapToHtmlNode(string input)
{
    try
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(input);

        return doc.DocumentNode;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<Uri> ExtractLinks(this HtmlNode node, Uri baseUri)
{
    var nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

    if (nodes == null || nodes.Count == 0)
        return Enumerable.Empty<Uri>();

    return nodes
        .Select(x => TryParseUri(x.GetAttributeValue("href", ""), baseUri))
        .Where(x => x != null && (x.Scheme == "http" || x.Scheme == "https"))
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var fragmentIndex = x.ToString().LastIndexOf("#", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (fragmentIndex == -1)
                return x;
            return new Uri(x.ToString().Substring(0, fragmentIndex));
        });
}

static Uri TryParseUri(string url, Uri baseUri)
{
    Uri newUri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, url, out newUri))
        return newUri;
    return null;
}

static ImmutableDictionary<string, string> ExtractHeaders(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var headers = response.Headers
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value.First()));

    var contentHeaders = response.Content.Headers
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value.First()));

    return headers
        .Concat(contentHeaders)
        .ToImmutableDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
}
```

And:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 5000;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    var hosts = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\domains.txt");

    var handler = new WebRequestHandler
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        UseProxy = false,
        Proxy = null
    };

    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
    };

    var semp = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

    foreach (var h in hosts)
    {
        semp.Wait();

        WebExtensions.GetPageAsync(client, 5242880, new Uri(h))
            .ContinueWith(_ => semp.Release());
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    }
}
```

Comment: rule #1. never invoke the GC... its bad practice generally speaking and does not guarantee an immediate execution of the GC. you will also experience unexpected behaviour at times....

Comment: HttpClient is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. What happens in `TryMapToHtmlNode`?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, I know. The use of `GC.Collect()` in the code, is purely for debugging purposes.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I've added the "missing code" :-)

Comment: `using (response.Content)` should be `using (response)`. Not sure if that's the core problem though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Using reflector you'll see that when disposing a `HttpResponseMessage`, all it does is calling `Dispose` on the `Content` property.

Comment: As a matter of principle: you should act as if you didn't know that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Touché.

Comment: @ebb, on a side note, don't do the blocking `semp.Wait` in `Main`. Do it inside `GetPageAsync` as `await semp.WaitAsync()`, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22493662/1768303) for an example.

Comment: what difference would it be for debugging purposes or not? it wouldn't...